# Change cell color in Excel according to adjacent dropdown value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I understand how to make a dropdown list. I understand how to make conditional formatting change the color of a cell. What I do not understand is how to make conditional formatting change the color of a cell based solely on the state of another cell (not a comparison).

`A1` is a `No / Yes` dropdown list

`B1` is a criteria statement

If the user satisfies the criteria statement in `B1`, they select `Yes` on the dropdown list in `A1`. For quick reference, if possible, I'd like `B1` to change to a green background color on this event, and of course change back to no-fill if the dropdown is reset to `No`.

Is this possible in Excel 2003 and/or 2007?

Comment: ok, well - 3 minutes in and I've got a downvote, a star, AND a close! quite the potpourri of feedback!

Comment: In theory downvotes should be accompanied by some form of explanation. Question/answer solved my issue +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Excel 2007, 2010 or 2013, try

- Under the home tab select Conditional
  Formatting -> New Rule

[image: Select Conditional Formatting -> New Rule...]

- Use the *Use a formula to determine
  which cells to format*

[image: Use a formula to determine which cells to format]

- For Cell B1 the formula can be
  "=(A1="Yes")", and change the
  formatting back color to what you
  wish.

[image: Change color format]

- You can then extend the formatting
  from B1 to B? as required.

[image: Format from B1 to B?]