# Changing font properties of multiple cells based on one cell's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm putting to good use [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634632/change-cell-color-in-excel-according-to-adjacent-dropdown-value) of the Excel posts on **Conditional Formatting**, but I'm having trouble applying it to multiple cells. I have a row of cells:

```
F4;G4;H4;I4;J4
```

in which **G4** is a Yes/No dropdown list (these values come from another sheet). I tried:

> Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

in the **Format values where this formula is true** I inserted `=(G4="No")` and it would apply **bold + gray + strikethrough** to the row of cells mentioned above (including **G4**).

Problem: when I change the **G4** value to No, only the first cell - **F4** - changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `=$G4="No"` should work. Just like with formulas in a cell.

Comment: That's the glitch. Thanx!

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, but it's fine. Your answer is good and I'm not here for the rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @hsan:

> =$G4="No" should work

but also the "Applies to" range should be:

```
=$F$4:$J$4
```

Without the anchor (`$`) the references are relative, so `F` triggers the formatting because, relative to `F`, `G` is one column to the right and from `F` one column to the right shows `No`. It may be easier to see what is happening if, with the “wrong” formula (but the same Applies to range of `F:J`) you change the content of J4 to `No`. I4 should now be formatted bold+grey+strikethrough.

Maybe think of the CF as rastering through the specified range, so where that is `=$F$4:$J$4`, it starts in F4 and considers “does G4 equal `No`?” then steps to G4 and asks “does H4 equal `No`?” – and so on.

With the anchor, the comparison is against ColumnG at every step in the cycle.